# UltiSnips not work all the time

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

I have configured UltiSnips for vim as described in the documentation of UltiSnips

```
" Track the engine.
 Plugin 'SirVer/ultisnips'

" Snippets are separated from the engine. Add this if you want them:
Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'

" Trigger configuration. Do not use <tab> if you use 
 https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-b>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"

" If you want :UltiSnipsEdit to split your window.
let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical"
```

Except that I am using [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) and the directory for the plugins is `~/.vim/bundle`.

My problem is that it seems as if my snippets won't get triggered every time. I have a test snippet in my `all.snippets` which I can't execute. But I have added another trigger in my `html.snippets` which I can execute in html files.
I then tried to save a snippet in the `vim.snippets` which again cannot get executed or triggered. Is there another thing I have to configure?

Although I have added `let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical"` to my `.vimrc`, it just does not want to start my `/ultisnips/<filetype>.snippets` in a vertical window it always starts in a seperate vim buffer.^

Edit: 
Here is my real .vimrc

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/bundle')

Plug 'honza/vim-snippets'

Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:vimtex_view_method='zathura'
let g:vimtex_quickfix_mode=0
set conceallevel=1
let g:tex_conceal='abdmg'

Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips'
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger='<tab>'
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger='<tab>'
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger='<s-tab>'
let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit='vertical'

call plug#end()
```

I have created an html file and added some snippets for html files. These snippets work. Then when I try to add some snippets to my `all.snippets` file which should be executed no matter in what kind of file I am, if I get that correctly. But this is not the case. Only one snippet file seems to work.

I have found out something about this problem:
My test html file is in `~/Projects/learn_vim/testing.html`. When I use the `:UltiSnipsEdit` command, it does not place the `html.snippets` file where it is usually placing my snippet files: it placed it at this location: `~/Projects/learn_vim/UltiSnips/`. And this file seems to work.

So I checked it further and it actually seems like it always creates an folder in the directory I am in with the snippet files.
Could I just define one place for all my snippets?

Also I have found out what my "vertical" problem was, see my `.vimrc` :)

Thank you for the patience

Comment: Please include exactly your code, and not something close to it, unless its an MCVE. Please clarify “snippets wont get triggered every time [sic]” and “it always starts in a separate vim buffer.” Using the [edit] button to spruce up your question with these details will dramatically increase the chance that someone is able to help you.

Comment: Also see https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604

Comment: Does it make any difference if you define the `g:___` options _before_ calling `Plugin`?

Comment: Do not mix several issues into one question. The "vertical" problem has nothing to do with the original problem. Could you post your `runtimepath` value for the filetypes it does not work (`:set rtp?`) which UltiSnips uses to find directories with snippets definitions. You find all the details about this under [`:help UltiSnips-how-snippets-are-loaded](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/6fdc3647f72e0a1f321ea6bd092ecd01f7c187ba/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L523-L585).